# Multithreaded http post from ajax control

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, multithreading, proxy

I'm currently writing a program that is attempting to send multithreaded HTTP POST packages. Each thread has its unique proxy server. Originally I've used the .net HTTPWebRequest function to accomplish this task.

However, I've found that the data submitted by the browser actually comes from an ajax control inside a javascript file, which HTTPWebRequest will certainly be unable to analyze. I've tried to use Selenium but it is too heavyweight.

(Update: Let me briefly explain why HTTPWebRequest will be difficult to analyze the data since the posted data actually is an encrypted key, encrypted by two algorithms: CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 and OpenPGP (PGencode.js). If I want to submit the data package by HTTPWebRequest I have to re-implement these two algorithms in C# to mimic the behavior and get the exact encrypted key, which is a bit cumbersome.)

Are there any alternative approaches that can support multi-threaded HTTP message posts together with ajax and js support?

Comment: Why do you think `HTTPWebRequest` would be unable to process the data? Could you update your question with some of this data?

Comment: Is you question "how to generate SHA256 signed and PGP encrypted message without access to keys?"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: No, actually I have access to keys. But I want to know if there's a clean way to mimic this behavior so that I don't need to reimplement the algorithms.

Comment: Than easiest way may be to find OpenPGP implementation for .Net and use it (SHA256 is part of framework) and construct message. You may also may try to use Javascript.Net (part of framework too) to use JS you are interested (also you unliklely to find help/tutorials on it).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Thanks for the reply. So are there any lightweight browser control methods?